# Passing JSON data to MVC controller property as array (model binding)

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to pass an integer array using jQuery Ajax but my controller does not seem to be receiving the data.

jQuery AJAX call:

```
var box = {MECallButtons: R_MainEntranceButtons }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/CollectJson/",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(box),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Data model:

```
Public Class MyParamModel
    Private f_MECallButtons(100) As Integer
    Public Property MECallButtons(ByVal Index As Integer) As Integer
        Get
            Return f_MECallButtons(Index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            f_MECallButtons(Index) = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Controller:

```
Function CollectJson(ByVal test As MyParamModel) As JsonResult
    Return Json("12345")
End Function
```

Mozilla Console (Json data sent):

```
{"MECallButtons":[4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

In visual studio all elements in the property array are `0`. I don't seem to be receiving the first `2` elements `4 & 1`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So....if you put a breakpoint in `Function CollectJson` and inspect your test variable, you get all zeroes? ....if not, then I think that you class definition is the guilty!

Comment: yes all zeros when setting breakpoint

Comment: I don't think you need to stringify your data before passing it to the controller. Just try `data: box` instead.

Comment: Yeah Stringify is the cause. If you want that to work then the parameter for your `CollectJson` would be `test As String`. Remove the stringify.

Comment: I'm trying to store all values of the Json string in to an integer array using the Property MECallButtons as an array. eg. test.MECallButtons(0) = 4, test.MECallButtons(1) = 1

Comment: What happens if your parameter for the controller is `MECallButtons as Integer()`?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Stringify and assigning the object to post should work.

```
var box = {MECallButtons: R_MainEntranceButtons }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/CollectJson/",
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: {model: box},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Then set the parameter name in the controller to

```
Function CollectJson(ByVal model As MyParamModel) As JsonResult
    Return Json("12345")
End Function
```